# Android: How to select Random value from an Array and then remove that selected value

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to select a random value from an Array but I don't know how can I remove it, function is properly generating random numbers from Array.

Help me Please that How can I remove selected number from my `randomNumbers` Array

This is My code

```
    static int[] randomNumbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

public static int randomArray(){
    java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
    int first = randomNumbers[rand.nextInt(randomNumbers.length)];
    return first;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot delete anything from an array.

Arrays are of fixed size in java. You can use `ArrayList<Int>` for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you Let me see what I can do with ArrayList<int>